# DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo inconsistent date patterns?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, globalization

According to MSDN, the static property [DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.invariantinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) "*gets the default read-only DateTimeFormatInfo object that is culture-independent (invariant)*".

Yet the long date pattern is "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy", giving a format like Monday, 29 February 2016. This format is commonly used on the continent in western Europe.

The short date pattern however is "MM/dd/yyyy" which results in a format 02/29/2016. This format is commonly used in the USA.

Even worse, when trying to convert to sortable format "s", this FormatProvider will result in 02/29/2016 00:00:00, which is hardly sortable.

Is this inconsistent behaviour a bug, or is it a compromise to "culture-independant"?

Comment: I believe en-US short date is single month digit, not zero padded. That said, it doesn't change the question.

Comment: From what I can see in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/calendardata.cs,045e92053a4b3c84), it's all just hard-coded without many comments explaining why, other than perhaps `// Set our default/gregorian US calendar data`. So the issue might not be that it is inconsistent, maybe it is, but you'd need to find the definition for expected formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems standard behavior to me. DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo means neither a neutral nor a specific culture but it generates a format which can be converted to any culture specific format. As you can see in [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/calendardata.cs) it is English language based but not culture specific (en but not en-US). Also your observation:

> The short date pattern however is "MM/dd/yyyy" which results in a
>   format 02/29/2016. This format is commonly used in the USA.

Is not correct because en-US culture ToString("d") will give 2/29/2016 (no leading). Also the time is in AM or PM.